# Marquee text not working in widget

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

Here is the situation, i have a widget containing two text views and i want the text to scroll if its width exceeds the layout width. The problem is that, the marquee is working for bottom text view but its not working for the upper one. I am attaching the code snippet. Can you tell me what i am doing wrong?

```
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/left"
        android:layout_width="97dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/place"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:lines="1"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:textColor="@color/white" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/weather_report"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/place"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:lines="1"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:textColor="@color/grey" >
        </TextView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You can refer the link below.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9568023/marquee-not-working-while-using-in-multiple-textviews/9568638#9568638

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this, works for me:

```
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/fact" 
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:text="Loading... More text to see if it spans or not and want more"
    android:singleLine="true" 
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit ="marquee_forever"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:duplicateParentState="true">
   <requestFocus 
      android:focusable="true" 
      android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
      android:duplicateParentState="true" />
</TextView>
```

Comment: at the beginning, i missed to note that String must be wider than defined width to enforce marquee effect and scrolling of text :)!

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:scrollbars = "horizontal"` in the textview of your xml file. In java code use:

```
textview.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

Comment: Hey, I have tried android:scrollbars in the textviews but its not working. Only the bottom one is able to scroll and the top one remains static. Also i don't think you can use setMovementMethod() method for remote views.