# Android Widget with 2 TextView Marquee not work

Tags: android, widget, textview, marquee

I'm developing widget using Marquee TextView, when i insert 1 Textview it's work fine but when i insert 2 Textview, first textview did't marquee.
Maybe it's because i'm using request focus on my textview so when i insert another text view it's will be lost focus

This is a code

```
     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/runText1_txtRunningText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="1lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 2lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 3lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor">
        <requestFocus android:focusable="true" android:focusableInTouchMode="true" android:duplicateParentState="true" />
    </TextView>
```

I already try using custom textview which run marquee automaticly without having focus but it's not work in widget..

What's should i do ?

Comment: i encounter the same problems as yours, have you figured it out now?

Comment: not yet, finnaly i change my widget interface with 1 marquee text only

Comment: I have faced the same and found a fix [Please try this code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35725649/1811356)

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/mywidget"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
    android:lines="1"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:text="Simple application for marquee with example as shown"
    android:textColor="#ff4500" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/mywidget1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
    android:lines="1"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:text="haihaihaihaihaihaiahaiahaiahaiahaiahaiahaiahaiahaiahaiahiaha"
    android:textColor="#ff4500" />
```

Try the above code may be it will help for you